# Trace of power of random matrix / sum of random variables with semicircle distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-graphs, random-matrices

I want to calculate the expectation value for the trace of the $m$-th power of the $n\times n$ adjacency matrix $A$ of a large Erdos-Renyi random graph (without self-coupling, i.e., all diagonal elements of $A$ are equal to zero). I was planning to use the invariance of trace under a change of basis and write

$\forall m<n:\:\:\:tr(A^m)=\sum_{i=1}^n\nu_i^m.$

Wigner's semicircle law states that in the asymptotic limit, the $(n-1)$ eigenvalues $\nu_1,\dots\,\nu_{n-1}$ have the semicircle probability distribution function

$f(\nu) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2}\sqrt{4\sigma^2-\frac{\nu^2}{n}}$

with second moment $\sigma^2$ of the distribution of the non-diagonal elements of $A$.

Since $tr(A)=0$ (no self-coupling), I know that $\nu_n=-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\nu_i$. My plan was to calculate the pdfs for $\nu_i^m$ and $tr(A^m)$ via multiple convolutions of $f(\nu_i)$ with itself. However, I already struggle with calculating the convolution of two semicircle pdfs,

$f(\nu_i)\star f(\nu_j):=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\nu_i)f(\nu_j-\nu_i)d \nu_i$.

How can I calculate this convolution? Or is there a better way to calculate the expectation value of $tr(A^m)$, that is, the expectation value of a non-linear function of $(n-1)$ iid random variables with semicircle pdf?

EDIT:

Since I am only interested in the expectation value of $tr(A^m)$, I do not need a pdf for $tr(A^m)$, because

$\langle tr(A^m)\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle \nu_i^m\rangle=(n-1)\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\nu)\nu^md\nu+\langle \nu_n^m\rangle.$

However, I believe I still need the convolution of semicircle distributions for calculating

$\langle \nu_n^m\rangle = (-1)^m\langle \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \nu_i^m\rangle.$

Comment: I think we need to know the joint distribution of $\{\nu_i\}_{1,...,n-1}$ to answer this problem. For example, if $\{\nu_i\}_{1,...,n-1}$ follow the GOE joint distribution, then we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\nu_i$ is Gaussian (the trace of a gaussian matrix) and the $\left<tr(A^m)\right>$ will be easy to express in terms of moments of gaussian and semicircle distributions. If the eigenvalues are independent (and if they are, I'd be interested to see the proof), then things will be complicated...

Comment: @D.A.N I am unfamiliar with the GOE joint distribution. Could you please provide some more info? I don't understand why the eigenvalues of _A_ should follow a GOE joint distribution. _A_ is the adjacency matrix of an Erdos-Renyi random graph, so the entries of _A_ are not drawn from a Gaussian distribution. The distribution of all but one eigenvalues of _A_ are given by the semicircle distribution _f(nu)_ which is also not Gaussian.

Comment: Here is a link to the joint pdf for GOE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix#Gaussian_ensembles. I'm not saying the eigenvalues are GOE either, and I have no idea what the proof is that the eigenvalues of a Erdos-Renyi graph follow the semicircle distribution. I mentioned the GOE since it is an example where the marginal distribution of an eigenvalue, in the aymptotic limit, follows a semicircle distribution, but the trace is not a convolution of semicircle random variables since the eigenvalues are not independent. Why do you believe your eigenvalues are independent?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt on an exact answer, which is not yet complete.
(if you want an answer in the form of a limit as $n \to \infty$, take a look at the proof of Proposition 4.1 of [these lecture notes](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~tkemp/247A.Notes.pdf), on which this answer is heavily inspired)

It is well known that given the adjacency matrix $A$ of a graph $G$,
$\operatorname{Tr}(A^m)$ is the number of
closed walks of length $m$ in $G$
(since $(A^m)_{ij}$ is the number of walks of length $m$
beginning at $i$ and ending at $j$).
So here's a combinatorial approach to
$\left< \operatorname{Tr}(A^m) \right>$.

Assuming that we are dealing with a $G(n, p)$ graph
on the vertex set $[n]$, we have that

$\left< \operatorname{Tr}(A^m) \right>
= \sum_{i=1}^n \left< (A^m)_{ii} \right>
= \sum_{(i_1, \dots, i_m) \in [n]^m} \left< A_{i_1i_2} A_{i_2i_3} \dots A_{i_mi_1} \right>$

For $i = (i_1, \dots, i_m) \in [n]^m$,
denote $A_{i_1i_2} \dots A_{i_mi_1}$ by $A_i$
and let $E_i$ be the edge set
$\{i_1i_2, i_2i_3, \dots, i_mi_1\}$.
Since all $A_{jk}$, $j \neq k$, are independent indicator
random variables with probability $p$,
then $\left< A_i \right> = p^{|E_i|}$
(provided there are no self-loops in $E_i$,
in which case $\left< A_i \right> = 0$).
Let $W^m_e$ be the set of all closed walks of length $m$
on the vertex set $[n]$ with no self-loops
using $e$ distinct edges. Then

$\left< \operatorname{Tr}(A^m) \right>
= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{W \in W_i^m} p^i
= \sum_{i=1}^m p^i \#\{W \in W_i^m\}$

And all we are left to do is count how many walks we have in $W_i^m$.